# Login another salesforce org from salesforce record page

Tags: automation, salesforce, apex

I was wondering if it was possible to login to different salesforce environments (Sandboxes, scratch orgs, production env, etc) using either Apex/LWC/Aura (or anything that I can make a quick action to). For example, I have a list of credential records, with the username and password, and I would like to have a login button that creates a separate tab that can automatically redirect to that specific instance and log in.

Currently, if a user wants to login to a particular instance, they have to either go to test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com (depending on if it's a sandbox or production) manually, then copy the password and username in. The ideal situation is to have a login button that can do this automatically from the record page where the username and password is located.

I think previously this could have been accomplished through the URL, but salesforce has recently patched this out due to security concerns. Is there another good way to do this?

Comment: It's possible, with code-based development, but it's definitely a high-risk implementation. Why aren't users using a password manager?

Comment: This is mainly internal usage - we have QA teams that need to access upwards to 100+ orgs with different options, and while we're using the Salesforce ORGanizer, it has a maximum amount of 30 inputs - in addition, currently when the password/access updates within the credentials object, it doesn't update within the organizer right now, and given that we have a requirement that we change passwords every 30 days, it makes tracking really difficult and makes the manager redudant

Comment: Sharing credentials used to be a violation of Master Service Agreement, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974545/313628 out. I don't see it in recent text but maybe they just moved it around a bit. You may want to delete the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to solve two specific challenges:

- Your users need to be able to manage very high volume of credentials.
- You need authentication to survive password resets.

The clear solution, in my mind, is to use the OAuth Web Server flow to execute initial authentication and then store the refresh token that results from this flow. This token survives password resets, and may be used more or less indefinitely to create new access tokens - which users can then use to log in via a frontdoor link.

There's an out-of-the-box tool that does this already: the Salesforce CLI. You can authenticate orgs to its toolchain, name them, and subsequently access them with a single command (`sfdx force:org:open`). Users that prefer a GUI can access the exact same functions in Visual Studio Code.

---

If you're hellbent on doing custom development to handle this use case, you can, but you need to be very careful of the security implications. As one example, you could implement an LWC + Apex solution that executed the relevant OAuth flows against orgs and stored the resulting data in an sObject, then allowing users to click a button to generate a new access token and do a one-click login.

But... if you do this, you're storing highly sensitive credentials in *an sObject*, which can be accessed by your system administrators and potentially other users who have relevant permissions. That data could be exfiltrated from your Salesforce instance by an attacker and misused. There's all kinds of risks involved in storing that kind of credential, especially if any of them unlock orgs that contain PII or customer data.

Answer (score 0):

***One of the two*** best answers for that (the other one being 'pure Apex' and relatively more complex) is using **Flow**.

"You can use a login flow to customize the login experience and integrate business processes with Salesforce authentication. Common use cases include collecting and updating user data at login, configuring multi-factor authentication, or integrating third-party strong authentication methods.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA60b.png)"

"You can use login flows to interact with external third-party authentication providers by using an API.

For example, Yubico offers strong authentication using a physical security key called a YubiKey. Yubico also provides an example Apex library and login flow on GitHub. The library supplies Apex classes for validating YubiKey one-time passwords (OTPs). The classes allow Salesforce users to use a YubiKey as a second authentication factor at login. For more information, see yubikey-salesforce-client.

You can also implement a third-party SMS or voice delivery service, like Twilio or TeleSign, to implement an SMS-based multi-factor authentication and identity verification flow. For more information, see Deploy Third-Party SMS-Based Multi-Factor Authentication."

learn more here: [enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow_examples.htm&type=5)

Comment: From my understanding of login flows, don't they only start after a login request was received? My problem is that I'm having trouble even starting the login process - I could redirect to the proper login page (test.salesforce.com/login.salesforce.com) with the username, but since the URL Query was patched out the password can't be filled in any longer and requires the user to copy paste from the credentials records page - it's perfectly fine if they go through the normal MFA - it's just getting to that section that's the problem - or I might be misunderstanding flow.